# Extract Raster by Layer - empty raster

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am quite new to QGIS but used some ArcGIS before, so I thought this should be very easy to do, but I dont get good results.

I did the following steps both in 3.8 and 3.4:
Import Raster-Layer and Shapefile, go to **Raster** -> **Extraction** -> **Extract by Layermask**.

[image]

Now I get a result, but both bands of the results have only 0 values. 
Can someone help me pls?
Ty,
Felix

Comment: have you verified that both layers (raster and the polygon) are in the same crs? not just reprojected but having the same source crs? also try saving it in a permanent file, not just into a temporary one

Comment: I already saved it as permanent file (which gets produced but only 0s in it). Will check the crs, thank you!

Comment: I found out what happened: My input raster was already empty in the spots I looked at. So basically this can be closed.